# NSDate been released automatically resulting Bad exe error. iPhone

Tags: iphone, release, nsdate, retain

I have spent all day working on this, re-writing this many a times trying to get my head around it.

I have a set of dates declared in the Header

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSDate *time;
```

On view did load i read a string from a database, convert it to a date and set it to this variable.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd / MMMM / yyyy"];
time=[dateFormatter dateFromString:datetime];
```

if i NSLog time i get the date expected (although not the right format). if i then go to use the NSDate further on in the view i get a Bad Exe error, or error due to time being = to nil.

I dont understand it is almost like its not retaining it.

Whilst problem-solving i created a new date within an IBAction and tried to replicate the code above but where it was required and i get the same issue. I assume that it is dateformat issue but i am formatting it the same way it was originally written as a string.

What am i doing wrong? i cant afford to loose another day on this.

Cheer

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to the the property as `self.time  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:datetime];`or `[self setTime: [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTime]]`

If you just assign it using = without using self, it won't retain it, it will just transfer the pointer. using dot operator will make it retain it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Annoying it was something so simple. Thats for the explanation why as well! VERY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you're not setting the property. `time` isn't using the dot notation there. You either have to write that as (assuming the property exists on self), it one of two ways:

```
self.time = [dateFormatter dateFromString:datetime];
```

or

```
[self setTime: [dateFormatter dateFromString:datetime]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign it to your property using

```
self.time = [dateFormatter dateFromString:datetime];
```

Otherwise it doesn't get retained

Comment: Wow - four almost identical answers within 1 minute :-)

Answer (score 1):

try using self.time , this will go through the generated setter method, which will retain the date, at the moment you are just assigning it to the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: `self.time = [dateFormatter dateFromString:datetime];`